# Write C = (A+B)^2 in Assembly language and Convert to Machine Language

Tags: assembly, x86

Please I am working on an assignment which says :
Translate C = (A + B)^2 in Assembly Language to Machine Language.
I started by researching and writing out the assembly program thus :

```
MOV AX, A ; Move A to Register Ax 
ADD AX, B; Add B to A 
IMUL AX; Square(A+B) 
MOV BX, C ; Load c to Register Bx 
MOV BX, AX ; Mov (A+B)^2 to C in BX.
```

Pls am not very sure of this Assembly code and don't know how to convert it into machine language

Comment: Machine language for which architecture?

Comment: This doesn't make sense - where does C come from if C is also the thing you're trying to calculate?

Comment: I agree, the last but one line doesn't make any sense and the last one doesn't do what it's written.

Comment: @ Graham Borland : pentium iv

Comment: @ harold : I introduced C bcos I was trying to Store it into C which is contained in the Register Bx

Comment: @ zakinster : I made a mistake.. Pls Correct me

Comment: @Chidiebere Nomeh: comments like "Please sir I'm waiting" are frowned upon in this community. You're not supposed to wait for an answer, you're supposed to think yourself. [Read this.](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If your variables A, B and C are in-memory variables, then the code is almost correct.

You only need to change this

```
MOV BX, C ; Load c to Register Bx 
MOV BX, AX ; Mov (A+B)^2 to C in BX.
```

to this

```
MOV C, AX ; Mov (A+B)^2 to C
```

You convert assembly language programs to machine by means of an assembler, a compiler-like program that takes as input programs written in assembly language.

There are a number of different x86 assemblers out there. You need to choose one since they differ slightly (sometimes not that slightly) in the syntax and functionality.

If I were to make a 16-bit .COM program for DOS with NASM out of your code, I'd have to rewrite it like this:

```
; file: AddSquar.asm
; to assemble with NASM: nasm -f bin AddSquar.asm -l AddSquar.lst -o AddSquar.com

BITS 16 ; 16-bit code
ORG 100H ; IP of first instruction is expected to be 100H in .COM programs

    MOV     AX, [A] ; Move A to Register Ax 
    ADD     AX, [B] ; Add B to A 
    IMUL    AX      ; Square(A+B) 
    MOV     [C], AX ; Mov (A+B)^2 to C

    RET ; terminate .COM program, return to DOS

A   DW 3
B   DW 4
C   DW 0
```

The listing file produced (AddSquar.lst) contains all the instructions encoded (though, for some reason `ORG 100H` isn't taken into account in all addresses, probably all the addresses are always shown relative to the beginning of the code):

```
 1                                  ; file: AddSquar.asm
 2                                  ; to assemble with NASM: nasm -f bin AddSquar.asm -l AddSquar.lst -o AddSquar.com
 3                                  
 4                                  BITS 16 ; 16-bit code
 5                                  ORG 100H ; IP of first instruction is expected to be 100H in .COM programs
 6                                  
 7 00000000 A1[0D00]                    MOV     AX, [A] ; Move A to Register Ax 
 8 00000003 0306[0F00]                  ADD     AX, [B] ; Add B to A 
 9 00000007 F7E8                        IMUL    AX      ; Square(A+B) 
10 00000009 A3[1100]                    MOV     [C], AX ; Mov (A+B)^2 to C
11                                  
12 0000000C C3                          RET ; terminate .COM program, return to DOS
13                                  
14 0000000D 0300                    A   DW 3
15 0000000F 0400                    B   DW 4
16 00000011 0000                    C   DW 0
```

You can get the same in a hex viewer/editor of the binary file (AddSquar.com):

```
0000000000: A1 0D 01 03 06 0F 01 F7 │ E8 A3 11 01 C3 03 00 04  Ў♪☺♥♠☼☺чиЈ◄☺Г♥ ♦
0000000010: 00 00 00                │
```

You can also see the encoded instructions in the disassembly:

```
00000100  A10D01            mov ax,[0x10d]
00000103  03060F01          add ax,[0x10f]
00000107  F7E8              imul ax
00000109  A31101            mov [0x111],ax
0000010C  C3                ret
0000010D  0300              add ax,[bx+si]
0000010F  0400              add al,0x0
00000111  0000              add [bx+si],al
```

I used NDISASM for the above like this: `ndisasm -b 16 -o 0x100 AddSquar.com`.

If you want to convert assembly code into machine code by hand, I'm afraid you'll have to do it yourself as SO isn't the right place for extensive lectures on instruction encoding.

Get CPU manuals from Intel or AMD online. They are free. Read the chapters on instruction encoding and then do it by hand.

Comment: @ Alexey Frunze : Thanx, Alexey Frunze am very grateful

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of (A+B)² is correct, but you don't seem to store it in the right location, i would do :

```
mov ax, A  ; Move A to Register Ax 
add ax, B  ; Add B to A 
imul ax    ; Square(A+B) 
mov C, ax  ; Move (A+B)^2 to C.
```

But of course it depends of what A, B and C actually are...

Comment: @ Zakinster, Thanks so much. Your corrections have been noted. pls how about the equivalent machine code?

Comment: The object code depends on the underlying architecture, but if you've been asked to manually assemble this code, you probably have the corresponding opcodes.

Comment: @ Graham Borland: Sir a Friend of mine suggested that i should convert them individually.... Wats ur opinion?

Comment: Yes you just have to translate each instruction into its corresponding opcode.

Comment: @ zakinster, lets say we take line 2 and try to translate thus: 0011 00 0101 1001 0100 00 0101 1010. Do you mean like this for each individual line?

Answer (score -1):

Question:

Write an assembly language code to write subroutines for the following two binomial theorems:

```
SROUTINE_SUM:    SUM_SQ = (A+B)2 = A2 + B2 + 2*A*B

SROUTINE_DIF:    DIF_SQ = (A-B)2 = A2 + B2 - 2*A*B
```

Where `SUM_SQ, DIF_SQ,` A and B are predefined data labels while `SROUTINE_SUM` and `SROUTINE_DIF` are the subroutine names.

Testing values for A and B are 3 and 2 respectively.

You have to attach the snapshot of AFD debugger showing the calculated values in SUM_SQ and `DIF_SQ`.